# How can one clear org-babel (emacs-lisp) function error to execute other code blocks?

Tags: org-babel, error-handling

Revised to [hopefully] add clarity:
After trying to execute some elisp code in org-mode, I get an error related to a function definition. Once this error is raised, it is then returned when I try to execute *any* elisp blocks in org mode. The error is:

> org-babel-eval-headers: Wrong number of arguments: (lambda (key alist) (cdr (assoc key alist))),0

The only way I have been able to clear the error is to restart emacs, having also tried killing the buffer and searching for running processes.

Is there a way to reset the org-babel elisp stack/interpreter such that the function definition is cleared from memory without closing emacs completely?

**Bad Code:**
I hesitate to ask you to debug my code for me, but here it is in case it's easy to find --maybe that `lambda ()` ... statement is at fault?:

```
(defun keys (alist)
   (mapcar (lambda (x) (car x)) alist)
)

(defun values (alist)
   (mapcar (lambda (x) (cdr x)) alist)
)

(defun value (key alist)
   (cdr (assoc key alist))
)
```

This part iterates over EFFORT properties a section of the org file, calculates some costs, and then writes new properties.

```
(org-map-entries 
       (lambda () 
         (cond ((avm/org-has-property "EFFORT")
                (let* ( (rate average-rate)
                        (cost (avm/effort-cost (avm/org-get-property-as-working-hours "EFFORT") rate))
                        (oh-and-p  (* cost (+ overhead profit)))
                        (total (+ cost oh-and-p)) )
                  (org-set-property "Effort-Working-Hours" (format "%.2f" (avm/org-get-property-as-working-hours "EFFORT") ))
                  (org-set-property "Rate" (format "%.2f" rate ))
                  (org-set-property "Cost"  (format "%.2f" cost))
                  (org-set-property "Overhead-and-Profit" (format "%.2f" oh-and-p))
                  (org-set-property "Total" (format "%.2f" total))
                  ))

               ((avm/org-has-any-profiled-property (keys hourly-rates) "EFFORT")
                (let* ( (cost-alist (avm/profiled-efforts-to-costs hourly-rates))
                        (working-hours-alist (avm/profiled-efforts-to-working-hours hourly-rates))
                        (cost (apply '+ (mapcar 'cdr cost-alist)))
                        (total-working-hours (apply '+ (mapcar 'cdr working-hours-alist)))
                        (oh-and-p  (* cost (+ overhead profit)))
                        (total (+ cost oh-and-p)) )
                  (mapcar (lambda (x) (org-set-property (avm/profiled-property-name (car x) "Effort-Working-Hours") (format "%.2f" (cdr x)))) working-hours-alist)
                  (org-set-property "Effort-Working-Hours"  (format "%.2f" total-working-hours))
                  (mapcar (lambda (x) (org-set-property (avm/profiled-property-name (car x) "Rate") (format "%.2f" (cdr x)))) hourly-rates)
                  (mapcar (lambda (x) (org-set-property (avm/profiled-property-name (car x) "Cost") (format "%.2f" (cdr x)))) cost-alist)
                  (org-set-property "Cost"  (format "%.2f" cost))
                  (org-set-property "Overhead-and-Profit" (format "%.2f" oh-and-p))
                  (org-set-property "Total" (format "%.2f" total))
                  ))
               ))
       nil
       'file)
```

Config (just in case it is relevant in any way):

- Windows 10 - 64bit Intel
- Emacs 28.1

Comment: Show some code. Something, somewhere, is expecting a function to be called with zero args, and it's being passed your function that requires two args. A guess is that you're trying to use that function as a normal hook (which is passed no args). And if that hook is called multiple times then you can get the error multiple times.

Comment: I don't see what the question title has to do with the content of the question.